# Is there a way I can call a method from another class in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to see an updated balance when calling my `print_statement`? In my `Transaction` class, I am using an `@amount` and `@timestamp` instance variable to store a transaction into my `@transaction` instance variable in my `Account` class. I am then calling my `print_statement` method which only prints out the `@timestamp` and `@amount` for each transaction.

In my desired outcome, I need to also print out an updated `Balance` with each transaction. I am new to coding, so any advice would be much appreciated!

My desired outcome:

```
date || credit || debit || balance
14/01/2012 || || 500.00 || 2500.00
13/01/2012 || 2000.00 || || 3000.00
10/01/2012 || 1000.00 || || 1000.00
```

My current outcome:

```
2.7.0 :001 > require './lib/account'
 => true 
2.7.0 :002 > require './lib/transaction'
 => false 
2.7.0 :003 > account = Account.new
2.7.0 :004 > account.deposit(100)
 => [#<Transaction:0x00007f9eff8941a8 @amount=100, @timestamp="09/01/2021">] 
2.7.0 :005 > account.withdraw(50)
 => [#<Transaction:0x00007f9eff8941a8 @amount=100, @timestamp="09/01/2021">, #<Transaction:0x00007f9efd9673c0 @amount=-50, @timestamp="09/01/2021">] 
2.7.0 :006 > account.balance
 => 50 
2.7.0 :007 > account.print_statement
   date   || credit || debit || balance || 
-------------------------------------------
09/01/2021||100||  || Balance ||
09/01/2021||  ||-50|| Balance ||
 => [nil, nil]
```

Account class

```
require_relative 'transaction'
 
 class Account

  attr_reader :transactions

  def initialize
    @transactions = []
  end

  def balance
    @transactions.map(&:amount).sum
  end

  def deposit(amount)
    @transactions << Transaction.new(amount)
  end

  def withdraw(amount)
    @transactions << Transaction.new(-amount)
  end

  def header
    puts '   date   || credit || debit || balance || '
    puts '-------------------------------------------'
  end

  def print_statement
    header
    @transactions.map(&:formate)
  end
end
```

Transaction class

```
class Transaction
  attr_reader :amount, :timestamp

  def initialize(amount)
    @amount = amount
    @timestamp = Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
  end


  def formate
    if @amount > 0
      puts "#{@timestamp}||#{@amount}||  || Balance ||"
    elsif
      puts "#{@timestamp}||  ||#{@amount}|| Balance ||"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hello, @byronmac for getting a better answer you should add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You could show some code where you actually use your classes, at the moment you are just showing class definitions not the way we are supposed to use them.Think a way to keep track of a balance may be a class instance variable could help.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I updated my current outcome so that hopefully it sheds more light on how I am getting my current outcome? Just started reading into class instance variables, I will try and implement this if I can. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have a reference to an account associated with each transaction. You can then use that reference to access the account info you want.  Since it also seems like you would just have a list of transactions and not store a fixed balance, I think you will need a method to get the balance after any transaction.

First I added a `balance_after` method to Account to calculate the balance after any given transaction.  It does this by looking up the index of the passed in transaction and then summing up the amounts of all transactions prior to the one passed in.

```
require_relative 'transaction'
 
 class Account

  attr_reader :transactions

  def initialize
    @transactions = []
  end

  def balance
    @transactions.map(&:amount).sum
  end

  # new method to get the balance after a given transaction
  def balance_after(transaction)
    index = transactions.find_index(transaction)
    transactions[0..index].map(&:amount).sum
  end

  def deposit(amount)
    @transactions << Transaction.new(amount, self)
  end

  def withdraw(amount)
    @transactions << Transaction.new(-amount, self)
  end

  def header
    puts '   date   || credit || debit || balance || '
    puts '-------------------------------------------'
  end

  def print_statement
    header
    @transactions.map(&:formate)
  end
end
```

Next I added the account info into the Transaction and a method that calls `balance_after()` method on the account reference, passing a reference to current transaction.

```
 class Transaction
  attr_reader :amount, :timestamp, :account

  def initialize(amount, account)
    @amount = amount
    @timestamp = Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    @account = account
  end

  def balance()
    @account.balance_after(self)
  end

  def formate
    if @amount > 0
      puts "#{@timestamp}||#{@amount}||  || #{balance} ||"
    elsif
      puts "#{@timestamp}||  ||#{@amount}|| #{balance} ||"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey nPn, this works perfect, thank you for taking the time to help! This has brought to light how little I use or understand the self method and how I can improve my future work. Many thanks, all the best!

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, there are more that one way to call a method of a particular class within another class, the simple and shortest way (since you mentioned you are new coding I will only show you 2 ways to avoid confusions):

Let's say you are within your `Account` class, within a method you can create an instance of your `Transaction` object and call any function (in a public scope for simplicity of this example):

```rb
t = Transaction.new(...)
t.formate
```

This is similar to what you are doing when you write:

```rb
@transactions.map(&:formate)
```

Basically, that line above said for each instance of transaction in that list call the method `format`

The other easy way to achieve this is to define the method as a class method (`static` function in other languages like `C#` for example) something like:

```rb
class A
  def self.print_foo
     p 'Foo'
  end
end
```

With the above definition, you can do something like `A.print_foo`.

There are other ways to achieve this but I think these 2 are the basics.

NOTE: IF YOU ARE IN DIFFERENT FILES AND USING PLANE RUBY (NO AUTOMATIC FILE LOADER, YOU MAY NEED TO IMPORT/REQUIRE THE FILES, BUT THAT ALREADY HAS AN ANSWER HERE IN THE SITE )

Hope the above helps to clarify!

Comment: Hey r4cc00n, thanks you for the advice, I still need to work on how to effectively implement the self method, but this is very useful and i can't wait to learn more about it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There could be more than one solution.

I'll give you a simple example.
But first let me congrats with you, I like the way you coded so far, very clean and focused on the public methods for each class, a clear and meaningful API.

What you are missing is what data structure you need to rapresent the problem.

In my solution I will use a `Struct`, you may use a `Hash`, or may be you could build some method in `Transaction` where you keep track of the balance.
But I think that a partial balance is a matter of the `Account` class, so here it is a suggestion:

```rb
class Account

  attr_reader :transactions

  TransactionPartialBalance = Struct.new(:transaction, :balance_at_transaction)

  def initialize
    @transactions = []
    @transactions_with_balance = []
  end

  def balance
    @transactions.map(&:amount).sum
  end

  def deposit(amount)
    @transactions << Transaction.new(amount)
    @transactions_with_balance << TransactionPartialBalance.new(@transactions.last, balance)
  end

  def withdraw(amount)
    @transactions << Transaction.new(-amount)
    @transactions_with_balance << TransactionPartialBalance.new(@transactions.last, balance)
  end

  def header
    puts '   date   || credit || debit || balance || '
    puts '-------------------------------------------'
  end

  def print_transactions_balance
    p @transactions_with_balance
  end

  def print_statement
    header
    @transactions.map(&:formate)
  end
end

class Transaction
  attr_reader :amount, :timestamp

  def initialize(amount)
    @amount = amount
    @timestamp = Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
  end


  def formate
    if @amount > 0
      puts "#{@timestamp}||#{@amount}||  || Balance ||"
    elsif
      puts "#{@timestamp}||  ||#{@amount}|| Balance ||"
    end
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
  account = Account.new
  account.deposit(100)
  account.withdraw(50)
  account.balance
  account.print_transactions_balance
  # [#<struct Account::TransactionPartialBalance transaction=#<Transaction:0x0000562a986ecc38 @amount=100, @timestamp="10/01/2021">, balance_at_transaction=100>, 
  # #<struct Account::TransactionPartialBalance transaction=#<Transaction:0x0000562a986ecad0 @amount=-50, @timestamp="10/01/2021">, balance_at_transaction=50>]

end
```

Comment: Hey Giuseppe, thank you for taking the time over the weekend to help me with this project! This is a interesting way of getting the updated balance, I just need to implement into my 'formate' method in the transaction class. The 'TransactionPartialBalance' is esspically interesting, ill be sure to do some research on how I can use this in future projects. Thanks again, all the best